# Is "from among" strange or awkward or wrong?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

I uploaded my writing somewhere and a person in the comment section said "from among" is a strange English phrase. I had written something along this line:

> The algorithm selects the vehicle's velocity **from among** a set of discrete values.

Is that really strange? I am not sure if the reader was native speaker of English so I am wondering if it is bad English?

Comment: The first time I read it, I thought it sounded totally fine. I feel like I've heard it many times before. I've probably said it. Now that I look at it closely and think about it, it seems insane. What's the point of the word among? Thank you for bringing this up.

Comment: from a set of discrete values is enough; from among is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound wrong to me, but it may be simpler to omit **among**.